# Can we execute other process while MPI_Waitall is in progress

Tags: mpi

I like to execute a process while the mpi_waitall is performing blocking, is it possible?

```
recv(....)
send(....)

stream(..) // the process I want to perform while waitall is in progress
MPI_Waitall(...)
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? It is not clear why you would call `MPI_Waitall()` if you do not want to ... wait.

Comment: First of all "while `mpi_waitall` is blocking" makes no sense. However, you can indeed have operations between the `irecv/isend` calls and `waitall`, as long as they don't need the result of the receive operations.